# Validação e-mail via pattern

Tags: email, validação

Gostaria de definir o pattern de um campo para que sempre valide os e-mails digitados no formato : ***nome.sobrenome@minhaempresa.com.br***

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UsuarioEmail, 
new { 
      @class = "form-control", 
      id = "UsuarioEmail", 
      placeholder = "Endereço de E-mail (@minhaempresa.com.br)" , 
      ng_pattern = @"^/[a-z0-9._%+-]+@minhaempresa.com.br$/" 
})
```

Estou utilizando o pattern acima, porém não está funcionando. Como faço ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

Troquei ***ng_pattern*** para apenas ***pattern***.

A expressão pattern ficou:

```
pattern = @"^/[a-z0-9.]+[a-z0-9]@minhaempresa.com.br$/"
```